# Convert GMT date to timestamp

Tags: php

I have a date formatted in this way:

```
$data = 'lun, 19 giu 2017 16:30:00 GMT';
```

What I need is to convert this date, first to timestamp and after to another format, that's my code:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::RSS, $data);
$timestamp_date = $date->getTimestamp();
$postdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp_date);
```

I get this error on the second line:

```
FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean in
```

I tried to change this value `DateTime::RSS` with many others but no results yet.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.parse.php

Comment: Do you know what language `giu` is written on? Will it always be in the same language or it can vary?

Comment: Simple. Your date was not recognized correctly. See if the format you provided matches correctly

Comment: Ah, it's Italian.

Comment: Instead of `DateTime::RSS` you can define the format of your date string

Comment: @modsfabio just tried with no result

Comment: @HankyPanky how can I do?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález always italian

Comment: Try to replace `DateTime::RSS` with `'D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T'`

Comment: I don't know why I insist on pushing people's attention to the limit and ask two questions in the same comment xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.parse.php) class can be used to parse international date formats:

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'it_IT',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Europe/Rome',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
);
$ts = $fmt->parse('lun, 19 giu 2017 16:30:00 GMT');
echo $ts, PHP_EOL, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
```

```
1497889800
2017-06-19 18:30:00
```

Comment: The base problem is that the server API returns dates in a format that's not really suited for automated processing (most likely an overlook on their side).
If you can safely assume that dates will always be written in Italian (for instance, because it's a small Italian based company that doesn't work with international customers) this is the best approach. Please note that you may need to enable the `Intl` extension in your PHP installation.

Comment: Thanks bro! After your explanation I asked to who realized RSS feed to change language from italian to english in order to reuse my first code and it finally works! Thank's again